# Where should I ask a question about cellphone capability?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

[I asked a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1248624/is-there-a-way-to-stop-my-cellphone-from-connecting-to-a-cellular-tower), and found myself off-topic. Woops.

I've been trying to find where this question should be migrated, to no avail.

edit (duplicate) : This is strickly about a cellphone capability, not about network design and if carriers could allow or disallow it.

Comment: It looks like the most recent comment on that post on superuser should help -- I would've suggested the android stackexchange, but only because I didn't realize there's an apple stackexchange.

Comment: If the question is Android-independent, it's going to be closed at [android.se].

Comment: In cellular technology the eNB node do the selection for you, so it's all done on the carrier's side. Thus for me it's a question to ask to your carrier, and would sadly fall offtopic on android or apple's SE site IMO. (or anywhere else on SE) (as your carrier can send a RF tech to the site you have diffuculty on to troubleshoot the situation, and maybe to ajust the LTE tower after)